# Se agregan parámetros a elemento HTML que pisan los estilos

Tags: html, css

Me está ocurriendo algo que no alcanzo a entender. En un pequeño fichero donde tengo puesto un `<section>` que muestra una pequeña caja en la parte inferior para mostrar el aviso de las cookies.

El fichero en cuestión es este:

```
<?php if (!isset($_COOKIE["leido_cookie"])): ?>
  <section id='notshowdiv'>
    <?php if ($idioma_web == 'es'): ?>
        <p>Utilizamos "cookies" para ofrecerte una mejor experiencia de servicio. Al navegar o utilizar nuestros servicios, aceptas el uso que hacemos de las "cookies".</p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>We use "cookies" to offer you a better user experience. By browsing or using our services, you accept our use of "cookies".</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

       <div style="width:auto;margin-top:15px;">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="cookies_aceptar" value="value" onclick='ocultar()'>
          <label id="label_cookies" for="cookies_aceptar"><?php if ($idioma_web == 'es') {echo 'Aceptar';} else {echo 'Accept';} ?></label>
          <?php if ($idioma_web == 'es'): ?>
              <a class="mas_info_coookies" href="https://www.webcualquiera.com/es/foro/Feedback/Politicas-de-LaXtore/567/Politica-de-Cookies/">Más información</a>
          <?php else: ?>
              <a class="mas_info_coookies" href="https://www.webcualquiera.com/en/forum/Feedback/LaXtore-politics/635/LaXtore-cookies-policy/">More information</a>
          <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
  </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Pues el caso es que se me agregan unos parámetros que son los siguientes:

```
<section id="notshowdiv" datasqstyle="{&quot;top&quot;:null}" datasquuid="cb0790cb-877c-4525-b5d7-d4d8a9598093" datasqtop="1266" style="top: 1266px;">
```

No sé ni de dónde salen, puesto que no uso ningún tipo de plug-in ni nada por el estilo. **He probado a añadir estilos en línea pero me los machaca igualmente**. El problema es que el aviso de las cookies no se puede ver porque aparece la mitad, y no se pueden aceptar tampoco, con lo que salen a cada rato (pese a que apenas se vea).

Comment: A simple vista, pareciera que si estas usando *algo* para mostrarlo, y que dicho **algo** se llama (o sus siglas son) **"sq"** y usa los [`data-* attributes`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) para guardar información sobre su configuración

Comment: @Marcos Uso PHP puro, no uso ningún plug-in pero sí que parece que algo de eso hay, y me sorprende. He probado cambiando el tipo de elemento y el nombre del id, pero el problema persiste.

Comment: @JetLagFox mmm  me suena como que estas utilizando algun plugin del navegador, revisa esta [liga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49877398/how-to-find-root-cause-of-element-style-that-came-out-of-nowhere)

Comment: por casualidad no tienes instalado SEOQuake en Chrome?

Comment: @amenadiel No fastidies que es eso...lo tengo instalado hará 3-4 meses. Pero en local no me pasa esto, sólo en producción. ¡Si es eso me quitas un peso de encima!

Comment: Entiendo que SeoQuake permite compararte con otro sitios, pero se alimenta del comportamiento de los visitantes que tienen SeoQuake instalado. Para ello todos los que usan la extensión permiten compartir su navegación (anonimizada y agregada) con el resto a cambio de ver la de los demás y poder comparar cómo está tu sitio respecto a otros. Para eso SeoQuake te injecta algo. Pensaba que era JS pero aparentemente también hay mutación del DOM. Obviamente en local no se activa. Sus estadísticas se ensuciarían si comparasen sitios reales con localhost

Comment: Te confirmo que es por el plug-in SEOQuake. A mi me ha pasado lo mismo.